# Getting fully qualified FieldUserValue instead of actual user name from SharePoint

Tags: development, client-object-model, excel

I'm working on my first C# program, and it's a pretty simple program that uses a view of a SharePoint page to go through and delete things that are older than 5 days on that page. Before deleting the items, though, I want to export the files to be deleted to an Excel file. There are a number of fields we want to record from each list item, including Assigned To/Completed By. In the Excel file the value of these are showing up as Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue instead of the actual name of the person as shown in SharePoint. Is there a simple way of fixing this in the code, or is this a problem with using the view's XML to query SharePoint?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("url");
        Web site = clientContext.Web;
        List workQueue = site.Lists.GetByTitle("Work Queue");

        View view = workQueue.Views.GetByTitle("Cleanup - Prod");       
        clientContext.Load(view);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery { ViewXml = string.Format("<View><Query>{0}</Query></View>", view.ViewQuery) };
        Console.Out.WriteLine(query.ViewXml);
        ListItemCollection itemsToDelete = workQueue.GetItems(query);
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Retrieving Items");
        clientContext.Load(itemsToDelete);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\...\Desktop\oneQueue.csv"))
        {
            file.WriteLine("Id,Name,Status,Team,Created,Assigned,Completed,Assigned To,Completed By,E-Mail CC,E-Mail From,E-Mail Sender,E-Mail Subject");
            foreach (ListItem listItem in itemsToDelete)
            {
                Dictionary<string, object> values = listItem.FieldValues;
                List<object> fieldValues = new List<object> { values["ID"], values["FileLeafRef"], values["Status"], values["Team"], values["Created"], values["Assigned"], values["Completed"], values["Assigned_x0020_To0"], values["Completed_x0020_By"], values["EmailCc"], values["EmailFrom"], values["EmailSender"], values["EmailSubject"] };
                string fileEntry = fieldValues.Aggregate("", (entry, next) => entry + "\"" + next + "\",", entry => entry.Substring(0, entry.Length-1));
                file.WriteLine(fileEntry);
            }
        } 
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

The "values["Assigned_x0020_To0"], values["Completed_x0020_By"]," portion is where the Excel file is showing Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue.LookupValue` should give the username.

Have a look at [FieldUserValue members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.fielduservalue_members(v=office.15).aspx)

You can also query the user from User Information List to get full details of the user, as shown below:

```
 var spUser = user as FieldUserValue;
 var userInfoList = context.Web.SiteUserInfoList;
 context.Load(userInfoList);
 var query = new CamlQuery { ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='int'>" + spUser.LookupId + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>" };
 var users = userInfoList.GetItems(query);
 context.Load(users, items => items.Include(
      item => item.Id,
      item => item["Name"]));
 if (context.TryExecuteQuery())
 {
      var principal = users.GetById(spUser.LookupId);
      context.Load(principal);
      context.ExecuteQuery()
      username = principal["Name"] as string;
 }
```

You can also query for Email and other stuff.

Comment: This set up worked for what we needed to do. Thanks.

Comment: what is `user` in this example? (on the first line) I don't understand this answer..

Comment: `user` is the value of Person or Group column. `values["Created"]` this in the above question is `user`.